# Areca Palm just dry, or something more sinister?

Tags: diagnosis, palm

I have a palm which I've had for 18 months or so and it's the best growing palm I've ever had. Big, frequent fronds, and quickly grew about 2 foot. 
Occasional browning at tips, or dry-green leaves(not browning) and more watering solved it. 
I had overwatered it early and lost some branches that went yellow. (so this doesn't seem like overwatering)

In the past 2 weeks, it's suddenly going very brown from the tips. Very quickly a large branch went brown (not yellow) and lots of other leaves are going that way.

- All winter leaves basically stayed green. Flat temp dropped to sub-10 degrees sometimes.
- Watered less in winter, but still at least say, 500ml a week.
- It sits by a large south facing window.
- Weather here has been cold, then 2 weeks of very sunny warmth (palm getting lots of light behind a window), now back to mostly-cold & cloudy
- Get some spidermites, which I try and get rid of, but not an epidemic.
- Well draining pot (I water it until it flows out)
- Roots had hit the sides, but still room to grow downwards.
- A few new fronds are still appearing, but they're not as tall as the biggest ones I've had.
- I try and keep humidity up with water on radiator & vapour.
- I thought at first, they were burnt from being by the window during the sun, but then whole leaves went down.

I was concerned I had overwatered it in winter, so took it from it's pot to check it wasn't soaked, and the soil is very dry about 10 inches down. (Top 2 inches are still wet, but I only just watered it)
No sign of any bugs in the soil, but some white specs (perhaps mould but very tiny amounts) near some roots...

Have I just under-watered it during our very sunny period?
Is it craving a weekly heavy water?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I think this is similar; [My Areca Palm is dying](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/36510/my-areca-palm-is-dying)

I also noticed this new frond has gone all wonky... in case that's vaguely related :)
[image: Bendy frond]

Comment: while I obviously agree (hence my link :) I'm not getting spots mid-leaf. I'm not sure if that's THAT relevant though. I thought spots were possibly more of a sign of disease