# Help! Areca Palm with dry leaves

Tags: indoors, watering, palm, dryness

[Photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrDjb.jpg)

I'm pretty new to growing plants and this is the first plant that i care about.
I did bought this plant about a month ago and it was delivered as it is in the photos.
I've been watering it two to three times per week with about 1.5 liters (about 50 ounces) of tap water.
I live in the capital of Brazil, Brasília, which is very dry (10% to 40% humidity) and hot (18° to 35°C / 66° to 95°F) during the day.
The palm gets direct sun between 3 to 6 pm.
What may be causing the dry leaves?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help GardenGems and Colin. I did contact the place that i got the plant from and they said the dry leaves might be happening due to high concentration of fertilizer when the plant was moved to a bigger vase. They told me to keep watering as I was and get back to them in a month. I will post an update in a few weeks.

Answer (score 1):

There was a fairly recent [similar question in this forum](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/36510/my-areca-palm-is-dying) with good pictures and an upvoted answer which may provide some guidance. Watering is critical - you might want to query the water supply people to find out what acidity level it has plus any contaminants such as level of chlorine which can be detrimental.

Your picture does not indicate the actual size of the pot of soil it has available. For a dry location such as Brasilia you might want to consider putting the palm in a pot that is somewhat too large for the top growth. This will allow the roots some growing space and a buffer of moist compost to keep the main root ball at an even level of moisture. Also it is helpful to have easy access to the soil surface to assess whether watering is required or not.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look around at young palm trees the best ones with no sunburn get lots of bright light, but no direct light.  Young palms naturally grow under the bright dappled light of older larger palms trees.

Also, when a plant, whether it shade or sun loving, gets sun for the first time during an intense time, like late afternoon that sun tends to burn a plants leaves.  This plant just gets no chance to acclimate before it is hit by that sun.  I know it's past 2pm, so it sounds safe, but it still a shock.

If you can give the plant more light, but more indirect light that would be best &/or follow Colins advice for watering and pot size.